# SwiftUI why can't I make a stored property a view with a modifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a View and I wanna make a stored property inside it and add a modifier to it, but when I try to do this:

```
var heyButton2 = Text("T").background(.red)
```

I get this error: Property definition has inferred type 'some View', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration

Now if I make heyButton2 a computed property everything works as expected but could someone explain why this isn't okay if it's a stored property?
Do I just not understand how exactly view modifiers work? I'm creating a Text view and adding a background modifier to it I don't see exactly why this would cause any problems.

Also another related question, if I remove the modifier from heyButton2, so just

```
var heyButton2 = Text("T")
```

I can just put 10 heyButton2's in a VStack or anything and each one will be a "different"? button? It just seems a little weird to me because it's just one variable containing a View but I can contain put it in any View ten times or something and they'll all be different, is it fair to assumt that each time I put a heyButton2 in a VStack it's just creating a copy of the button? Like the original heyButton2 is a variable containing one View but each one I put into a VStack is just a copy, would that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to views specifically; you probably should rephrase the question. You just can't have type inference for opaque types. E.g.

```swift
struct S {
  var bool = someExpressibleByBooleanLiteral
}

var someExpressibleByBooleanLiteral: some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral { true }
```

Fix it by explicitly typing with `some Protocol.` This does **not** require a computed property, as you suggested. That’s simply an option.

Comment: So following @Jessy your code works if you do: `var heyButton2: some View = Text("T").background(.red)`

Answer (score 0):

You need explicitly provide type, like

```
var heyButton2: some View = Text("T").background(.red)
```

because `Text` generates known `Text` type (your second snapshot), but modifiers declare (almost always) undefined `some View` that should be inferred.

Tested with Xcode 13.4

Answer (score -1):

I think that answer would help you. Actually it's weird but simple, if you look definition of "background" it has a return type some view. Therefore return type must be 'view' but your variable type isn't that.
[definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdQlJ.png)